# Facebook post not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I've one web application running on Tomcat at 8080 port. In this web application I've one html page which has Like button. My requirement is if user hit on Like button then link should get posted in facebook wall. 
I've created facebook app with below details - 
App domain : 123testdomain123.com
Site URL : http://123testdomain123.com

Now I've added this in host file :  127.0.0.1       123testdomain123.com

Below is the code to display like button in html page -

```html
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
      </script>

     <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://testdomain.com:8080/myapp/abc.pdf">
```

After all this things are setup, when I click on Like button then I see that it is giving me option to Post to Facebok with comment box. But when I click on Post to Facebook button then its not posting successfully on my Facebook wall.

Then I used debug tool to verify whether url is correct or not -
http://123testdomain123.com but I'm getting error like "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped." 
I could not find proper answer to this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually linking the like button to a .PDF url? 
If so, don't.

I'm assuming your URL is reachable by Facebook's crawler; if not, it needs to be.

The URL you point use in the Like button's `href` parameter needs to be a real webpage which returns the meta tags telling Facebook about the image, title, etc to use for that URL.
Put the URL you're trying to Like into [Facebook's Debug Tool]

(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it'll show you what Facebook sees

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Basically  Facebook should recognize .pdf url. Before that I tried to debug that URL using tool but there itself I'm getting error - "Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

Comment: That URL does not load for me, nor for the debug tool - the domain isn't even registered. the URL **must** be a real URL which is accessible to Facebook's crawler

Comment: This URL is my laptop host machine URL which I created by making entry in host file. If I understood you correctly, then URL must be accessible from internet otherwise I cannot connect? Is there no other way to make it work from localhost ? Please advice

Comment: The URL must be a real URL which is accessible to Facebook's crawler; otherwise it cannot retrieve the meta tags describing that URL - even if the like went through without the metadata, users wouldn't be able to access the URL anyway...